# Trying to import a CSV file with polygons to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, csv, import

I have a CSV file with polygons. 
I have created table 'sinikia' like this:

```
CREATE TABLE askisi.sinikia ( 
    sinikia_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),  
    area NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    perimeter NUMERIC NOT NULL,                                                                                
    geom geometry(polygon, 2100));
```

and tried to import my CSV file, which looks like this: 
[image]

and I got a PARSE ERROR. I have also tried to put brackets (single and double) to the geometry column, taking the same error.

Afterwards I created another table and instead of geometry I set column 'geom' as a TEXT.

```
CREATE TABLE askisi.sinikia ( 
    sinikia_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),  
    area NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    perimeter NUMERIC NOT NULL,                                                                                
    geom TEXT);
```

Importing CSV worked fine but now I can not ALTER column geom from TEXT to GEOMETRY.
I am probably missing something. Is there any idea?

Comment: where is your polygon stored? can you add a single (small) example of what it looks like

Comment: sorry but i am new to postgis and i don't undrestand your question. What do you mean where is my polygon stored?

Comment: i edited my post with my .csv first line attached

Comment: Try, or provide a link to download an example data in *.csv format, or insert it into the body of the text as a block in *.txt format ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those fields only contain numbers that are getting parsed as `TEXT` into a single string; PostGIS can only cast from valid WKT/WKB to `GEOMETRY` implicitly!

Best option would be to wrap those numbers per line in `'POLYGON(( <numbers> ))'`; assuming your `TEXT` column approach, try

```
ALTER TABLE askisi.sinikia
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 2100)
    USING ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || geom || '))', 2100)
;
```

---

Alternatively, assuming the `GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 2100)` typed column approach, wrap that field in EWKT (i.e. `'SRID=2100;POLYGON(( <numbers > ))'`) representation as above, but within the CSV; that way, a `COPY` would trigger the implicit typecast to `GEOMETRY` during import.

Comment: Thank you so much.. The TEXT column approach, worked for me with some changes..... ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON'|| geom ||')', 2100); and I replaced the double parenthesis at the end of my .csv file, with single...